# Help with this compile error

Tags: c++, linux

I just picked up an old project and I'm not sure what the following error could mean.

```
g++ -o BufferedReader.o -c -g -Wall -std=c++0x -I/usr/include/xmms2 -Ijsoncpp/include/json/ -fopenmp -I/usr/include/ImageMagick -I/usr/include/xmms2 -I/usr/include/libvisual-0.4 -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/SDL -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_SCRIPT_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/include/QtCore -I/usr/include/QtGui -I/usr/include/QtScript BufferedReader.cpp
In file included from BufferedReader.cpp:23:
/usr/include/string.h:36:42: error: missing binary operator before token "("
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.3/../../../../include/c++/4.4.3/cwchar:47,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.3/../../../../include/c++/4.4.3/bits/postypes.h:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.3/../../../../include/c++/4.4.3/iosfwd:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.3/../../../../include/c++/4.4.3/ios:39,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.3/../../../../include/c++/4.4.3/istream:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.3/../../../../include/c++/4.4.3/sstream:39,
                 from BufferedReader.cpp:24:
```

At line 24 of BufferedReader.cpp is `#include <string.h>`. I've tried it with just `<string>` but get the same thing. Any clue?

Here's the snippet of code from string.h

```
/* Tell the caller that we provide correct C++ prototypes.  */
#if defined __cplusplus && __GNUC_PREREQ (4, 4) //line 36
# define __CORRECT_ISO_CPP_STRING_H_PROTO
#endif
```

Does that mean __GNUC_PREREQ isn't defined?

Edit:

Changing `-Ijsoncpp/include/json/` to `Ijsoncpp/include` stopped the errors. I noticed I was including `<json/json.h>`.

I'm about to switch to JsonGlib though, which is the reason I pulled the project up again. So it's all good. :)

Comment: **@Scott** To follow along with guidelines please post your solution as an actual Answer and then Accept it.  Editing your solution into your Question makes it more difficult for users skimming a question for an accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try `#include <cstring>`.

Comment: cstring seems to include string.h and the error still happens.

Comment: @Scott, yes but if you're doing `C++`, it is still recommended to include `cstring` instead of `string.h`.

Answer (score 4):

Strange errors like this usually happen in the include file before the one you included. This is often when a class in a header file does not end with a semicolon (;). Check which file in included on line 22 of BufferedReader.cpp and check that file for syntax errors towards the end.

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this peculiar behavior is probably a file name collision: `string.h` includes `<features.h>` which should usually resolve to `/usr/include/features.h` or similar. But the `json/` dir also contains a `features.h`, so if it comes first in the include path, that will be included instead, although it probably serves a different purpose than `string.h` needs.